# How to create a "creatable" qml singleton?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a use case where I need to instantiate a singleton in qml (for property bindings).

i.e:

*File*: `main.qml`

```js
Item{
    MainQuery{id: mainquery
        graphql: `query MainQuery{...}`
    }
    Text{
        text: mainquery.data
    }
}
```

This other file should use the query defined in `main.qml`

*File*: `otherfile.qml`

```js
Item{
    import MyLib 1.0 as Gql

    Text{
        text: Gql.MainQuery.data
    }
}
```

However if you use [`QML_SINGLETON`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlengine.html#QML_SINGLETON) you can't initialize it in QML
and in order to bind to the `graphql` property above you would have to use
[`Connection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-connections.html).

Is there a better solution?

Note:
The object should be a singleton in CPP / Python side as well.
currently it is implemented in python like this:

```py
class QSingleton(type(QObject)):  # type: ignore
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        super().__init__(name, bases, dict)
        cls.instance = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = super().__call__(*args, **kw)
        return cls.instance

class BaseQuery(QObjcet, QSingleton):
    ...

@QmlElement
class MainQuery(BaseQuery):
   ...
```

And gives this nice error when the qml engine tries to initiate the type:

```
QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

(**I do have an eventloop running**)

Comment: If it's a singleton and accessible in C++, I don't see how you can possibly "instantiate" it in QML. That statement is a contradiction.

Comment: @StephenQuan That's the reason it is in quotation marks. ("createable")

Comment: I just need it to look like it is instantiatable via qml in order to use property bindings with ease.

Comment: Yes, though I think I'll go for another path, I'll use another type that will set the `graphql` property on the singleton.

Comment: Can you include the C++?

Comment: currently it is implemented in python. and the code is auto generated so roughly it looks like above ☝️.

Comment: source code is here https://github.com/nrbnlulu/qtgql/blob/main/qtgql/codegen/py/runtime/queryhandler.py

Comment: Did you also check the [Binding](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-binding.html)?

Comment: @SMR it is similar to `Connection`

Answer (score 0):

Whether the underlying Python object is or is not a singleton it doesn't matter. We can always declare a singleton wrapper in QML by defining a `qmldir` and using `pragma Singleton` in our source file. To demonstrate this approach, I wrap `TextMetrics` in my singleton object and expose `TextMetrics` properties as properties of my singleton so that I can use property binding with singleton syntax:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    Frame { 
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        ColumnLayout {
            TextField {
                text: "Hello"
                onTextChanged: MyWrapper.tmText = text
}
            Text {
                text: MyWrapper.tmWidth
            }
        }
    }
}

// qmldir
module ExampleWrapper
singleton MyWrapper 1.0 MyWrapper.qml

// MyWrapper.qml
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Item {
    property alias tmText: tm.text
    property alias tmWidth: tm.width
    TextMetrics {
        id: tm
        text: "Hello"
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACcnicdVHbasMwDH33V4h+QLq9BvYUVlZYYWWDPptYJGa+1VZYw+i/z3HSNJdVL7qdc4QkqZ31BEc6NrL8ZnKWZoU15K0Ky/o7b21DgX3wCuGXQbSd5zrGkJLOuClr60NWoiH0e5OD4z7GI6CwqtGmlxpEbvaFF9pJVGJR74xiL4fNGyplN6uuNR23qLmpUORwaE+eO4c+I9014CXx2XU17uGkqcRJCqpnuLtQH12jNNtu4ayVkJ5pKxqF8Hrh2ikchFiQplJI1tzF4Tl7moyK9CQzrzjPK83h80ZfvOXh9/aEetjPeRvVqAWuJA/QXyWPPkt3+ReStk6Yn3H/jnZA8rIMk8tJ0cHGdP2qeJ4/mci8IA==)

References:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html